# Параллельный запуск функций как?

Tags: многопоточность, golang

Моя попытка:

```
func func1(c chan string,i int) <-chan string {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int31n(5)) * time.Second)
    c <- "func " + strconv.Itoa(i)
    return c
}

func func2(result chan string, msg string) <- chan string {

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(msg," =>" ,i)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int31n(20)) * time.Second)

    }
    result <- "func 2 off"
    return result
}

func main() {

    result := make(chan string)
    e := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func1(result, i)

        res := <-result

        if res != "" {
            go func2(e, res)
            q := <- e

            if q != "" {
                fmt.Println("ок")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Подскажите как запустить функцию 1 и 2 параллельно?

Comment: Вы запускаете горутины и тут же ждёте их результата. Конечно у вас всё в один поток. Разработайте свою программу как конкурентную, и почитайте про буферизованные каналы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как отметил Ainar-G, вы ждете результат горутины в основном потоке, поэтому основной поток останавливается до тех пор, пока горутина не запишет значение в канал. Для вашего примера, рабочий код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
    func func1(c chan<- string, i int) {
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int31n(1500)) * time.Millisecond)
        c <- "func " + strconv.Itoa(i)
    }

    func func2(result chan<- string, msg string) {

        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(msg, " =>", i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Int31n(1500)) * time.Millisecond)

        }
        result <- "func 2 off"
    }

    func main() {

        times := 5
        f1result := make(chan string)
        f2result := make(chan string)

        for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
            go func1(f1result, i)
        }

        for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
            res := <-f1result
            go func2(f2result, res)
        }

        for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
            q := <-f2result
            fmt.Println("ок " + q)
        }
    }
```

В это примере мы запускаем пять горутин сразу, одна за другой.
Затем мы пять раз ждем результат выполнения этих горутин, при этом, как только завершилась какая-то из горутин func1, мы сразу же запускаем одну горутину func2. И в конце мы ждем завершения работы всех горутин func2.

Какая-то из горутин func2 может завершиться раньше, чем запустятся все горутины func2, но они будут заблокированы каналом f2result, т.к. из него еще никто не читает. Чтобы позволить этим горутинам завершаться в свое время, мы должны читать из f1result и f2result одновременно. Тогда функция main будет выглядеть так:

```
    func main() {

        times := 5
        f1result := make(chan string)
        f2result := make(chan string)

        for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
            go func1(f1result, i)
        }

        go func() {
            for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
                res := <-f1result
                go func2(f2result, res)
            }
        }()

        for i := 0; i < times; i++ {
            q := <-f2result
            fmt.Println("ок " + q)
        }
    }
```